# Which matplotlib.axes methods are safe to call from a background thread?

Tags: matplotlib, wxpython

I’m writing an interactive application using wxPython and matplotlib. I have a single graph embedded in the window as a `FigureCanvasWxAgg` instance. I’m using this graph to display some large data sets, between 64,000 and 512,000 data points, so matplotlib’s rendering takes a while. New data can arrive every 1–2 seconds so rendering speed is important to me.

Right now I have an `update_graph_display` method that does all of the work of updating the graph. It handles updating the actual data as well as things like changing the *y* axis scale from linear to logarithmic in response to a user action. All in all, this method calls quite a few methods on my `axes` instance: `set_xlim`, `set_ylabel`, `plot`, `annotate`, and a handful of others.

The `update_graph_display` is wrapped in [a decorator that forces it to run on the main thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23374226/371228) in order to prevent the UI from being modified from multiple threads simultaneously. The problem is that all of this graph computation and drawing takes a while, and since all of this work happens on the main thread the application is unresponsive for noticeable periods of time.

To what extent can the *computation* of the graph contents be done on some other thread? Can I call `set_xlim`, `plot`, and friends on a background thread, deferring just the final `canvas.draw()` call to the main thread? Or are there some `axes` methods which will themselves force the graph to redraw itself?

Comment: No `Axes` methods should force a re-draw (and if you find any that do please report it as a bug), but I don't know enough about threading to tell you they will be safe.  You might get some traction using blitting and/or re-using artists as much as possible (via set_data calls), but you will have to write the logic to manage that your self.  Take a look at how the animation code works.

Comment: @tcaswell Can you write that as an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will reproduce @tcaswell’s comment:

> No `Axes` methods should force a re-draw (and if you find any that do please report it as a bug), but I don't know enough about threading to tell you they will be safe. You might get some traction using blitting and/or re-using artists as much as possible (via set_data calls), but you will have to write the logic to manage that your self. Take a look at how the animation code works.